# Deleting specific files based on filename from terminal

Tags: files, rm

I have a directory containing files with names

```
rho_0.txt
rho_5000.txt
rho_10000.txt
rho_150000.txt
rho_200000.txt
```

and so on. I would like to delete all those that are a multiple of 5000.

I tried the following: `printf 'rho_%d.txt\n' $(seq 5000 10000 25000) | rm`, but that gave me the response `rm: missing operand`.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Regardless of how you do this, I recommend (for safety) moving the desired files into a directory, then when you've confirmed that all and only the files to be deleted are in the directory, delete the directory.

Comment: Safety is important here. I generally test these these things with `ls` first.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You don't need a loop or extra commands where you have [`Bash Shell Brace Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

```bsh
rm -f rho_{0..200000..5000}.txt
```

**Explanation**: `{start..end..step}`. The `-f` to ignore prompt on non-existent files.

---

P.s. To keep safety and check which files will be deleted, please do a test first with:

```
ls -1 rho_{0..200000..5000}.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

`rm` doesn't read from standard input.  You could do:

```
for i in $(seq 5000 5000 25000); do
    rm -i rho_${i}.txt
done
```

I include the `-i` option to `rm` to prompt before removal so that you can verify the behavior.  Once you're confident it's doing what you want, you could omit that option.

Edit: Alternatively, you could do:

```
for ((i = 5000; i <= 25000; i += 5000)); do
    rm -i rho_${i}.txt
done
```

That form may be more familiar if you've done any programming.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot pipe to a program as if the content of the pipe were arguments. It's sent through stdin.

You should use xarg for this purpose :

```
printf 'rho_%d.txt\n' $(seq 5000 10000 25000) | xargs rm
```

but first you can give a try with echo to see if everything is as you intend :

```
printf 'rho_%d.txt\n' $(seq 5000 10000 25000) | xargs echo
```

Comment: If your version of `seq` has the `-f`/`--format` option you can use that instead of this work-around with `printf` and command substitution.

Comment: Thank, I've just answered using the command used in the question and trying to explain his rm error

Answer (score 9):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but if all the files that start with `rho_` are of this form, isn't it equivalent to do

```
rm rho_0.txt rho_*[05]000.txt
```

Since a number (other than 0) is a multiple of 5000 if and only if it ends in 0000 or 5000.

(0 is a special case, since it is a multiple of 5000, but is typically written without additional leading zeros.  If you didn't intend to include 0, then take it out of the above line.)

Of course this should only be used if all the `rho_*.txt` files in your directory have the desired form.  Don't use it if your directory also contains `rho_please_dont_delete_me_5000.txt`.

(Math note: This works precisely because all the prime factors of 5000, namely 2 and 5, are also prime factors of the base we are working in, 10.   Equivalently, there is a sufficiently large power of 10 (namely 10000) which is divisible by 5000.  There is no similar trick for matching all those which are multiples of 3000.)

Comment: This actually is the best answer.